# Is there a graphical pager?

Tags: gui, pager

Does someone know of a GUI application (X/GTK+/Qt/whatever) that can be used instead of `less` or `more` for viewing text, specifically one piped in from standard input? Ideally looking for something that can also run on Mac OSX (or maybe even just on Mac).

I'm looking to introduce UNIX newbies to the wonderful world of command line text processing (with `awk`, `sed`, `grep` and even some `perl`) and it would be useful to show them the text using a nice GUI that allows interactive search, scrolling with the mouse (I know most Linux terminals support mouse scrolling with less, but Mac terminals do not), etc.

The best thing I found so far was to pipe input into `zenity --text-info`, but that viewer is **very** limited and does not even allow searching.

Comment: If you're on _gnome_: `command | gedit -` (note the trailing dash)

Comment: You can pipe with `command | gvim -`, if that counts.

Comment: There's not much point in using GUI apps if you're piping. Why not just redirect to a temp file instead?

Comment: @terdon - I'm not sure why you say there isn't much point. The main problem with a temp file is that they're not that temporary, you have to remember to delete them. Also when you run multiple things at the same time - messing with files easily gets out of hand.

Comment: @don_crissti: cool, I didn't think of using `-` as the input specification for `gedit`. It works nicely, though I think the `leafpad` solution is cleaner for about the same capabilities. Other editors I've tried using `-` with didn't work well :-(

Comment: @Sparhawk - but then again, gvim is not much different than less: except being its own window, it has basically the same features and the same "non user interface" ;-)

Comment: I mean that piping stuff is primarily a CLI thing. If you put a GUI viewer into the loop you sort of break continuity. Then again, I am very used to the CLI so it might be just me. As for dealing with them, just use `file=$(mktemp)` and that will i) create a different file per process so you don't have to worry about name collisions and ii) create it in `/tmp` where they will be deleted automatically on the next reboot (depending on how your system is setup).

Comment: Or kate with `command | kate -i`.

Comment: @terdon: meh, looks like too much scripting for just running some `grep`s.

Comment: @Sparhawk - now that's something I can get behind! I need to try `man <some gui app>` more: Kate is my preferred editor and I wasn't even aware it had all those useful flags :-) . It does basically everything I need, even running on Mac (with some fiddling). If only you'd post it as an answer...

Comment: @Guss yes, that's why I said "if that counts" for `gvim` :) I'll post the `kate` answer up.

Comment: @Guss, if you "introduce UNIX newbies to the wonderful world of command line text processing" ... then why you should use graphical tools? maybe you just need to change your approach to the "introduction" and start by introducing UNIX newbies to editor available in from command line where mouse is pointless?

Comment: @Scantlight: to "ease their pain" ;-)

Comment: @don_crissti It appears the `-` option isn't available in all versions of `gedit`; I have 3.4.2 (from Debian 7), and that option appears not to work.

Comment: @KyleStrand - yes, most likely a bug - I can't remember exactly whether it was [this one](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-May/msg01886.html) or another one...

Comment: Good question. Have you run across a lightweight pager-only (not editor) ? By "lightweight" I mean: doc < 5 pages, builds on a Mac with no Qt in < 10 minutes.

Comment: I found "trowser", its is a GUI application built using tcl/tk - which isn't really a modern UI toolkit, but should still work find on Mac. It has some useful capabilities but after looking at if for a few minutes I decided not to use it because it looks like a refugee from 80s IBM workstations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Kate

You can pipe into kate, using `command | kate -i`.

From `$ man kate`:

```
   -i, --stdin
       Read the contents of stdin
```

### Kwrite

You can pipe into kwrite with `command | kwrite -i`.

From `$ kwrite --help`:

```
-i, --stdin                Read the contents of stdin.
```

### Gvim

Somewhat facetiously, you can also pipe into `gvim` with `command | gvim -`.

Comment: How exactly is that facetious? Gvim is perfectly appropriate for moments when you need w̶a̶f̶f̶l̶e̶s̶ a graphical text editor. That's the whole point.

Comment: @BradenBest Facetiously, because gvim isn't a "normal" GUI program. IMO there's not a massive amount of difference between piping to gvim or vim.

Comment: Except gvim doesn't need a terminal. I can open my `dmenu` launcher and type `ls | gvim -` and get a gvim window with the results. No terminal emulator necessary. I could also do this from an ssh or TTY with the appropriate `$DISPLAY` setting.

Comment: @BradenBest Agreed, but I still wouldn't call gvim a "nice GUI" for "UNIX newbies", as per the question.

Comment: I dunno, the GUI looks reasonably user-friendly to me. Sure the menu has like a billion functions and it isn't as simple as gedit or sublime, but if my first vim experience was with GVim, I'd at least have been able to exit the editor without Google's help :P Besides, you don't need any vim knowledge to use it as a pager. Can scroll with arrow keys, page up/down and mouse wheel no problem. I get what you're saying, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe into `leafpad`. I don't know if there's a Mac port though.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't familiar with `leafpad`. I think its the only text editor that does this. The only downside I can see, compared to `less`, is that it supports BiDi "too well" and if my log lines start with Hebrew dates then the entire log line is right aligned. its worse if only some lines start with Hebwer. I found no way to disable that.